# How to make image zoom in transition when hover on javascript / css

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations, css-transitions

i'm trying to achieve this effect where when users hover over a div, an image will appear, and users can click on the div to be redirected to a link.

I'm able to make the image appear now and follow the cursor, but I'm struggling to have any nice transform transitions (i.e image zoom in from scale(0.2) to scale(1) when the div is hovered over). Now it just does a opacity transition.

Here is my HTML code, I have a prop called 'site' that contains fields such as the image source, title and link to redirect to. My main problem is at the image-container class div:

```
<template>
    <div class="reveal-site" @mouseover="showImage(site, $event)" @mousemove="updateImagePosition(site, $event)" @mouseleave="hideImage(site)">
    <a :href="site.link" class="site-link" target="_blank">
        <div class="site">
            <span class="site-title">{{site.title}}</span>
            <span class="site-sub">{{site.sub}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="image-container" id="image">
            <img v-show="site.showingImage" :src="site.src" :style="imageStyle(site)" class="site-image" />
        </div>
    </a>
    <hr>
    </div> 
</template>
```

and I have the following functions:

```
        imageStyle(site) {
            return {
                width: `450px`,
                position: 'fixed',
                top: `${site.mouseY}px`,
                left: `${site.mouseX}px`,
                transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
                zIndex: 4,
            }
        },

        showImage(site, event){
            site.showingImage = true;
            this.updateImagePosition(site, event);
        },

        updateImagePosition(site, event){
            site.mouseX = event.clientX;
            site.mouseY = event.clientY;
            //this.imageStyle(site);
        },

        hideImage(site) {
            site.showingImage = false;
        },

        handleGlobalMouseMove(event) {
        // Check if the mouse is outside the element's boundaries
        const rect = this.$el.getBoundingClientRect();
        if (
            event.clientX < rect.left ||
            event.clientX > rect.right ||
            event.clientY < rect.top ||
            event.clientY > rect.bottom
        ) {
            // Mouse is outside the element, so hide the image
            this.hideImage(this.site);
        }
        },
```

and my CSS:

```
.site-image {
  border-radius: 10px;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1));
  opacity: 0; /* Initially hidden */
  transform: scale(1.2);
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out, transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transform-origin: center;
}


.image-container:hover .site-image {
  opacity: 1; /* Fade in on hover */
  transform: scale(1); /* Zoom in on hover */
}
```

so the .site-image 'transition' doesn't work for the 'transform' field, but it works for the opacity. I suspect that it's because of how i set the style in the imageStyle(site) function.

Please help, I just want to make a nice scale effect (from scale(0.2) to scale(1.0)) when the div is hovered over and the image appears